# How can I debug the meteor's linking phase right after compiling but before app running?

Tags: typescript, meteor, angular-meteor

I wrote code in typescript and added adornis:typescript package. Then I ran meteor --inspect-brk.

However it reported an error while started to run app right after compiling. And I cannot get hooked to debug;

The error was:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`
[COMPILER]: Starting build for web.browser with TS version 3.4.2 
                rebuilding accounts-phone.ts 
                ......
                Finished build for web.browser in 25389ms.
/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/coffeescript/.1.0.17.1u2icau.t097++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileCoffeescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:116
      throw error;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:95:33)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:155:16)
    at Function.SourceNode_fromStringWithSourceMap [as fromStringWithSourceMap] (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:80:26)
    at /tools/isobuild/linker.js:781:38
    at reallyRecompute (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/optimism/lib/entry.js:301:28)
    at recomputeIfDirty (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/optimism/lib/entry.js:259:12)
    at Entry.recompute (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/optimism/lib/entry.js:87:10)
    at optimistic (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/optimism/lib/index.js:82:23)
    at File.getPrelinkedOutput (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:722:12)
    at walk (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:357:23)
    at _.each (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:366:11)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at walk (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:364:11)
    at _.each (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:366:11)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at walk (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:364:11)
    at trees.forEach (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:386:7)
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Module._chunkifyModuleTrees (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:384:11)
    at Module.getPrelinkedFiles (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:185:24)
    at Object.fullLink (/tools/isobuild/linker.js:1071:31)
    at buildmessage.enterJob (/tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:1657:28)
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at PackageSourceBatch._linkJS (/tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:1656:18)
    at PackageSourceBatch.getResources (/tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:1547:28)
    at sourceBatches.forEach.sourceBatch (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1145:37)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ClientTarget._emitResources (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1127:19)
    at buildmessage.enterJob (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:847:12)
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at ClientTarget.make (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:835:18)
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:3143:14
    at webArchs.forEach.arch (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:3294:25)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:3248:14
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:283:5)
    at bundle (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:3124:31)
    at files.withCache (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:3069:32)
    at Object.withCache (/tools/fs/files.js:1712:12)
    at Object.bundle (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:3069:16)
    at Profile.run (/tools/runners/run-app.js:569:24)
    at Function.run (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:490:12)
    at bundleApp (/tools/runners/run-app.js:568:34)
    at AppRunner._runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:610:35)
    at AppRunner._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:908:28)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:398:12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bookheart-admin@0.4.3 admin: `meteor run --inspect-brk`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Usually I can debug after the app run. But this error occured just before that. How can I debug it to figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Error itself suggested solution. Read it carefully. You need to run
`npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`

```
=> Started proxy.                             
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`
[COMPILER]: Starting build for web.browser with TS version 3.4.2
```

Comment: caniuse-lite is not related. It's always there among other projects.

Comment: Yes, But its's asking to update the version. Read it carefully